# Can a cyclic group have more than two generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Can a cyclic group have more than two generators?

for example the group $\mathrm{Z}$ has two generators $-1$ and $1$, but can a group have more than two generators?

Comment: A cyclic, or not,  group can have lots of sets of generators with different cardinalities, yet a **cyclic group** is characterized for having a generator set with one single element. Of course, a generator for a cyclic group and *any* other element(s) will also be a generator set.

Comment: @435145 See the Wikipedia article on Cyclic groups! - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Integer_and_modular_addition

Answer (score 2):

Yes, take $G=\mathbb Z_5$ then it has a $\phi(5)=4$ generater.

In general $Z_n$ has $\phi(n)$ generater where $\phi$ is Euler phi function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that, I have just a basic knowledge about group theory.

Comment: @435145: Ok, by writing expilictly, you can see that $Z_5$ has $4$ generator. i.e every nonidentity element is a generator.

Comment: Maybe to be a bit clearer: Every finite cyclic group has a generator for each number coprime to the order of the group, and less than the order. Since 5 is prime, all numbers less than 5 are coprime, so there are 4 generators. On the other hand, the cyclic group of order 10 also has 4 generators: 1, 3, 7 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Recall that in $\mathbb{Z}/n$, the order of $a$ is $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,a)}$. Therefore the number of generators of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is just the number of elements prime to $n$, which is $\phi(n)$.