# Prove that any finite cyclic group with more than two elements has at least two different generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

Prove that any finite cyclic group with more than two elements has at least two different generators.

Attempt: Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group with 3 elements, say $e,g,g^{-1}\in G$ such that $e=$identity element. If $G$ is a cyclic group then it must have a generator, say $g$. If $g$ generates $G$ then so does $g^{-1}$ since $o(g)=n$ implies $g^n=e$, and $g^{-n}=(g^{-1})^n=e.$ Therefore, $G$ has at least two generators; $g$ and $g^{-1}.$

(I know this is a possible duplicate but I am asking a question specifically about my proof. Is it correct?)

Comment: I think that you should say that $G$ is a finite cyclic group with **at least** three elements, then label three of them as $e$, $g$, and $g^-1$. The rest of the proof looks fine to me.

Comment: Or you could say, for n>2, there are two prime numbers less than n.

Comment: @jnyan I cannot see the relevance of prime numbers less than $n$, and it in any case it is not true for $n=3$.

Comment: Cyclic group is isomorphic to Zn. So one generator is fixed. For given Zn, prime numbers will be generator. For this case consider 1 as prime, since it will also be generator.

Comment: The title is a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226985/can-a-cyclic-group-have-more-than-two-generators), but what you are asking about your proof is OK. However, a much better idea would be to see *in general* that a cyclic group of order $n$ has $\phi(n)$ different generators. And $\phi(n)\ge 2$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Note: $(g^-1)^n=e$ does not exactly proof that $o(g^-1)=n$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments $g^{-n} = e$ does not imply that $g^{-1}$ has order $n$, only that the order of $g^{-1}$ is a divisor of $n$. You should base your proof that the number of elements of order $n$ is $\Phi(n)$ (the Euler totient function).